# How to continue a script when web elements are not present in the page

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, testng

I am trying to select an option from a drop down. If there is no drop down options are visible then script execution should continue.

Please find my code below -

```
List<WebElement> drop_down_options = driver.findElements(By.className("mat-option"));
if (drop_down_options.size() == 0) {
    System.out.println("drop down options are not visible");
} else {
   drop_down_options.get(0).click();
}
```

Here It is taking long time to execute the script if there are no drop down option is present. In my web page some of the drop downs are disabled (which has default value) so I don't want to click or select the option.

But it stuck for some times(more than 4 minutes) in the first line of the code which I mentioned above.

Even if there are  element is not visible it waits for some time,so that my script takes time to execute.

I have tried by

1. `isDisplayed()`, `isEnabled()` ,`isPresent`
2. try catch

Please give me a solution to continue my script if there are no elements visible in the page

Updated comment:

I have tried all the solutions as mentioned below

1.In first option   Select select = new Select( drop_down_options); shows me error saying that "cast argument drop_down_options to WebElement"

2.where as in the second option getText() returns place holder value and other help text message near the input field
 GetAttribute() returns null

3. tried with below code but same result which takes time to exceute if there are no options

   ```
       for (int d = 0; d < dropdowns.size(); d++) {


               Thread.sleep(1000);

               System.out.println("----------------" +dropdowns.get(d).getAttribute("value"));
               System.out.println("----------------" +dropdowns.get(d).getText());


                   dropdowns.get(d).click();

                   Thread.sleep(1000);

                   WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,10);

            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElements(drop_down_options));

            try{

                   if (drop_down_options.size()==0) {

                       drop_down_options.get(0).click();


                   }
               }catch(Exception e)
               {

               e.printStackTrace();

               }
   ```

Comment: Must the wait (implicit and explicit ) causing the issue. Is the class name `mat-option` is unique in your page ?

Comment: Yes mat-option is unique in my page, where there are different types of input attributes in my dynamic web page so I am trying to iterate those fields using class name.

Answer (score 0):

If your DOM is using options tag for drop down then try below :

```
List<WebElement> drop_down_options = driver.findElements(By.className("mat-option"));// Assuming class name is from parent tag.
Select select = new Select(drop_down_options);
List<WebElement> allOptions = select.getOptions();
```

option 2

- try to get default value of dropdown using gettext() or getattribute()
- you can check attribute value is =="DISABLE" don't click.
- Or you can get default value and check if it is not null then only perform click action

Option 3

- try and catch {} it should  work if not working put your work and details. Juts a note Catch should not have return statements to continue after your exception.

Comment: I have tried all three solution and please find the  updated comments above

Comment: can you share your URL. May be you need to check your xpath.